# How to get tags parameters with NSXMLParser in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

In `XML` struct i have:

```
<font fontsize="10" fontcolor="#000000" fontface="file.ttf"/>
```

How do i get fontsize, color and face using `NSXMLParser`?
Of course i have the standard implementation

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myxmlfile" ofType:@"xml"]]];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{
    NSLog(@"Started Element %@", elementName);
    element = [NSMutableString string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"Found an element named: %@ with a value of: %@", elementName, element);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (element == nil)
        element = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [element appendString:string];
}
```

And it works beautifly for a `<mytag>something</mytag>`. How to get tag attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `attributeDictionary` from

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

contains them. Just call `[atrributeDict objectForKey:@"fontColor"]` for example

Answer (score 2):

The NSXMLParserDelegate protocol has a [`– parser:foundAttributeDeclarationWithName:forElement:type:defaultValue:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser%3afoundAttributeDeclarationWithName%3aforElement%3atype%3adefaultValue%3a) method that the parser uses to tell the delegate about each attribute. Implement that method in your delegate and you'll get the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Use xpathQuery.. Its the most simple, quickest solution for XML parsing.. This will solve your problem..
here is the link..

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html

BTW: for 'query'  part, you need to put '//' for root element, '//root//item' for inner hierarchy for example.